# Lorentz invariance, locality and unitarity of the S-matrix

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, scattering, s-matrix-theory

I am reading [these](https://agenda.infn.it/event/18103/sessions/13962/attachments/63647/76681/Baumann-Long.pdf) notes on cosmological bootstrap by Baumann and found the following statement, which I am trying to understand / see where it comes from [page 2 of the linked notes]:

"[...] S-matrix bootstrap, where the structure
of scattering amplitudes is fixed by Lorentz invariance, locality and unitarity:

$$A(s,t) = \sum a_{mn}s^n t^m + \frac{g^2}{s-M^2} P_S \left( 1+ \frac{2t}{M^2}\right)$$
"

Essentially he says that Lorentz invariance, locality and unitarity fix this form of a scattering amplitude. I am asking myself three things regarding these three aspects:

1. **Lorentz invariance**: Shouldn't this imply that $A$ depends on lorentz-invariant quantities only, i.e. $s,t,u$ and not only $s,t$?
2. **Locality**: Why does locality imply that the only poles appear in internal propagators? (similar, currently *unanswered* question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/78186/locality-in-the-scattering-amplitude))
3. **Unitarity**: In the notes he connects the $g^2$ with unitarity, but I cannot see the connection here. What does unitarity exactly imply in this context?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.